# XML Schema Pattern Error

Tags: java, regex, validation, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to write an XML schema. The specifics require me to validate a field so that it starts with a letter, followed by alphanumeric characters (e.g. Foo3x4 is valid, 3Foo or Foo3_ are not).

This is how I wrote it:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="nameType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="^[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

But if I try to validate a document that has as nameType the value H0, it gives me the following error (translated in English by me):

> cvc-pattern-valid: The value "H0" is not valid as facet for the pattern "^[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$" for the type nameType

I can't get why. Using it on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) (`/^[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$/gm`), it works. Am I missing something in the pattern specification?

One last detail. The validation error is given by the marshaller in the JAXB Java framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `^` and `$` as [XSD patterns](https://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) are anchored implicitly and `^` and `$` are not used as anchors in these patterns, and fix the typo in the `[a-zA-z]` character class, it should be `[a-zA-Z]` if you need to match any ASCII letter (see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926), `[A-z]` does not only match ASCII letters).

Use

```
<xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*" />
```

This pattern will actually match the following

- implicitly matches the start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]` - any ASCII letter
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - zero or more ASCII letters and/or digits.
- implicitly matches the end of string